# PHP String Comparison Not Working

Tags: php, cookies, string-comparison

I am having an issue with PHP String comparison.  It never turns out to be 0.  Below I am trying to get a setting in a cookie and compare it with a given key, and return the value of that cookie.  The cookies looks like this console=1|userId=5.  The value is always -180 or something.  I echo them out and the are the same, and the lengths are the same.  Could it be an encoding issue?

```
$parameters = explode('|', $_COOKIE[Cisco_Rewards::REWARDS_SETTINGS_COOKIE_NAME]);

            for ($i = 0; $i < count($parameters); $i++) {
                $parameter = explode('=', $parameters[$i]);

                if(count($parameter) > 1) {
                    echo strcasecmp(strtolower(trim($parameter[0])), trim(strtolower($name)));
                    if(strcasecmp(strtolower(trim($parameter[0])), trim(strtolower($name))) == 0) {
                        return $parameter[1];
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Does `$parameters` after first line contain expected value? Can you post result of var_dump($parameters) or just an example?

Comment: What that `return` stands for?

Comment: Array ( [0] => console=1 [1] => userid=8150 ) is returned by print_r($parameters), and the return, returns the value of the key, say 8150 for userid if that is requested via $name.

Comment: echo strcasecmp(strtolower(trim($parameter[0])), trim(strtolower($name)));
 returns -180

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing **break;** in [for loop](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php)!

Yes, it could be encoding issue because function [strcasecmp()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcasecmp.php) works with Unicode only. Multi-byte characters such as UTF-8 or UTF-16 cannot be compared with [strcasecmp()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcasecmp.php).

Also, [strcasecmp()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcasecmp.php) is case-insensitive function so using [strtolower()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php) against its parameters doesn't change function's result (string "example" is same as "EXAMPLE"m "eXaMPlE", "ExamPlE", etc).

You should set default result value (like `$res=false;`) to be sure that result is set after loop.

You should replace [for loop](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php) block with [foreach loop](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) like this one bellow

```
  $parameters = explode('|', $_COOKIE[Cisco_Rewards::REWARDS_SETTINGS_COOKIE_NAME]);

  // this will handle result
  $res = false;

  foreach ($parameters as $value) {
    $param = explode('=', $value);
    if(count($parameter) > 1) {
      // I guess this line is just for testing result
      echo "param1=".trim($param[0])."; param2=".trim($name)."; Result=".strcasecmp(trim($param[0]), trim($name)) . "<br />\n";

      if(strcasecmp(trim($param[0]), trim($name))) {
        $res=$param[1];
        // you should break here
        break;
        }
      }
    }
  // try to output result before (testing purpose only)
  var_dump($res);

  return $res;
```

But to make this solution easy you can use this function

```
  function getParamValue($parameters, $key) {
    $res = false;
    $plist = explode('|', $parameters);
    foreach ($plist as $pair) {
      $element = explode('=', $pair);
      if (trim($element[0]) == trim($key)) {
        $res = trim($element[1]);
        break;
        }
      }
    return $res;
    }
```

So if you have `$parameters` string like `"console=1|userid=8159"` and want to find value for `$key` string `"userid"`, put it into this function and it will return your result or **false** if `$key` was not found in `$parameters` list.

Example

```
  $parameters = "console=1|userid=8159";
  $name = "userid";

  echo getParamValue($parameters, $name);
```

Output

```
8159
```

Now you can write your code this way

```
$parameters = explode('|', $_COOKIE[Cisco_Rewards::REWARDS_SETTINGS_COOKIE_NAME]);
$value = getParamValue($parameters, $name);
```

And **$value** takes your result or returns **false** if **$name** is not in **$parameters** list.

Comment: That worked.  I basically switched out the for loop with the foreach and kept the rest the same, while removing the string lower (that was just left over from trying everything).   Still not exactly sure what was wrong but thanks.

Comment: @Mike, probably logic error but the most important thing is, you've got solution. I suggest using this function I've put in bottom part of my answer instead of that foreach block.